# Store Procedure Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure and am receiving these errors. How do I rectify this?

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usbinsertbookDatainto, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure usbinsertbookDatainto, Line 22
Must declare the scalar variable "@currentnoofcopiesavillable".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would have to see the actual stored procedure SQL to be sure, but the errors are as follows:

- Near the `AS` keyword, you have mistyped / have invalid syntax near Line 8
- You have not `DECLARE`d `@currentnoofcopiesavillable`. Example being:

`DECLARE @currentnoofcopiesavillable int;`